# How to add scripts to user edit page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to include some scripts in  user-edit.php page in wordpress but the scripts not loading to the user-edit.php page and no errors

```
    function admin_scripts()
{
    global $pagenow;

    if ($pagenow == 'user-edit.php') {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js', array(), '2.2.0', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('users_scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/users_scripts.js', array('jquery-min') , '', false);
        wp_localize_script('users_scripts', 'users_const', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )) );
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts');
```

please any help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: *Not working*. What isn't working? Do you get any error?

Comment: No errors, just the scripts not loading to the user-edit.php page

Comment: Above script you have to add in User Profile edit in WP .?

Comment: yes, i need to add the scripts in User Profile edit in WP

Comment: You need a better approach to test your changes.